# TypeScript Files Importing 'Path' Where There is No 'Path' Package

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript-typings, angular-universal

I have been working with Angular Universal for a couple of weeks and I have noticed that many instances of Angular Universal have a **server.ts** document that is located at the root directory.

This **server.ts** file imports several TypeScript installations which are usually available from a /typings directory. However, there is one import library that always triggers an error when editing in the Atom IDE and disallows me to compile the file, only emit it:

```
import * as path from 'path';
```

Up until now, I have yet to figure out exactly where this 'Path' library is derived from. I have tried to install it using TypeScript itself:

```
typings install path
```

and I receive the following error:

```
typings ERR! message Unable to find "path" ("npm") in the registry.
```

Anyone familiar with this 'path' import reference and exactly where it is coming from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path` is a part of `node`.

So `typings install node` is the key! :)

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts#L2261

Comment: Thanks a million! Ask and ye shall receive an answer to your liking :-)